# Using wildcard in typescript generics

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

This might be a simple solution and I just did not come across it yet. Given a typescript function like `func<T, D = any>(param1: T, param2: D) { ... }` and I call it with two parameters `param1` and `param2`. Is it possible to specify the type of `D` without specifying the type of `T` so that typescript still infers the type of `T` but enforces the type of `D`?

**Example:** Let's say I want to enforce that this function is called with the type of an external interface definition:

```
export interface Data {
  field1: string;
  field2: boolean;
}
```

I can now either use `func('Hello', {field1: 'World', field2: true})` (this will not ensure that `param2` is a valid `Data` object) or I can use `func<string, Data>('Hello', {field1: 'World', field2: true})`. What I **don't want** to do is `func<any, Data>('Hello', {field1: 'World', field2: true})`. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called partial argument inference and is not supported at the moment. There is a proposal to add this but it is not actively being perused as far as I can tell.

You can use function currying to achieve this, although the result is not as pretty :

```
function func<T>(param1: T) {
  return function <D>(param2: D) {
    return [param1, param2]
  }
}  

export interface Data {
  field1: string;
  field2: boolean;
}
let a = func("Hi")<Data>({
  field1: "",
  field2: true
})


let b = func("Hi")<Data>({
  field1: 1, // err
  field2: true
})
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=20&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABKSAeAKgPgBQAcCGATvgLYCMAXIugJSIDeAUIooQKZQiFIrTxKoAIjgLESAJiqC6TFi3aduiANqjSZADSI1EgLrNEAX0aGWjRmwAeuOISiIYYKG0LB8ENokH4o+BgeAYNgAbABNKRABnKEJHAHMAbgCgsMlEACM4OGC2fDAk4xz7PwBeZHAIbAAiAAkYKpohH3wcWWQU8Koqqo1kkNC0mJA2ExpzRiKMxDLearqGpt9WvrCIzUQAeg3EF0IVgaohkcMaIA)